# Why do Cameron and the red-headed female Terminator stop fighting when humans enter the elevator?

Tags: the-terminator, the-terminator-series

In [Season 2, Episode 6](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_206%3a_The_Tower_Is_Tall_But_The_Fall_Is_Short) of *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, Cameron fights a red-headed female Terminator.

> When both machines reach for the same door, each realizes who the other is and they begin fighting in the elevator. When humans are about to enter, they stop fighting and face away so the humans won't notice the damage they've sustained. After the humans leave, they resume fighting.

This is normal for Cameron, since she doesn't want to blow her cover - but what about the other terminator? Other terminators, Cromartie especially, don't care to fight in front of witnesses. Why does this particular terminator care about that?

Comment: Just a thought, but seeing as how the red-headed Terminator didn't immediately recognize Cameron, it is safe to say that she had another mission to accomplish other than destroying Cameron, one that (presumably) relied on stealth and being inconspicuous.

Comment: This is what happens in Borat also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Rosie

> "Cameron struck first, initiating a fight between the two, which at
>   first appeared to be an even conflict, but Cameron quickly established
>   her superiority over Rosie. The fight took them back into the lift
>   where Cameron tried to dislocate Rosie's arms, but she proved to be
>   remarkably flexible and was able to overcome Cameron's forced
>   contortions. The fight came to an unexpected halt, however, as both
>   machines sought anonymity in the presence of humans. Once they were
>   gone, they resumed their fight, resulting in Cameron forcing Rosie to
>   the floor, who tried to retaliate by wrapping her legs around
>   Cameron."

The primary objective for both machines must have been for them to be as anonymous as possible around humans.